# Obtener 5 ultimos registros en BD con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

necesito obtener los ultimos 5 registros de una tabla ordenados por su ID, quiero saber si esta bien mi consulta:

```
public function getLastProductos(){
    $this->db->select("p.*, c.nombre as categoria");
    $this->db->from("productos p");
    $this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
    $this->db->order_by("id","desc");
    $this->db->limit("5");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

y como puedo pasarla al controlador para luego mostrarla en una vista?

este es mi controlador para listar una vista, pero como puedo integrarla aca, para mostrarla en mi vista?

```
    public function index()
{
    $data  = array(
        'permisos' => $this->permisos,
        'productos' => $this->Productos_model->getProductos()
    );

    $this->load->view("layouts/header");

    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/productos/list",$data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");

}
```

la funcion de getProductos es otra en la cual listo los productos de mi tabla, la cual es esta:

```
public function getProductos(){
    $this->db->select("p.*,c.nombre as categoria");
    $this->db->from("productos p");
    $this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
    $this->db->where("p.estado","1");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Listo, despues de realizar la consulta, de esta manera:

```
public function getLastProductos(){
     $this->db->select("p.*, c.nombre as categoria");
     $this->db->from("productos p");
     $this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
     $this->db->order_by('id',"desc");
     $this->db->limit(5);
     $resultados = $this->db->get();
     return $resultados->result();
```

}

Coloque en el controlador la funcion:

```
public function index()
{
    $data  = array(
        'permisos' => $this->permisos,
        'productos' => $this->Productos_model->getProductos(),
        'productoslast' => $this->Productos_model->getLastProductos()
    );

    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/productos/list",$data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");

}
```

Para por ultimo obtener la consulta ya ordenada en la vista de la siguiente manera:

```
<!-- ./col -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div> <strong>Ultimos 5 Productos Agregados</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Codigo</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Categoria</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php if(!empty($productoslast)):?>
                                <?php foreach($productoslast as $producto):?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto->id;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto->codigo;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto->nombre;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $producto->categoria;?></td>

                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: la consulta si es correcta

Answer (score 0):

el código debe ser como sigue:

```
public function getProductos(){
    $this->db->select("p.*,c.nombre as categoria");
    $this->db->from("productos p");
    $this->db->join("categorias c","p.categoria_id = c.id");
    $this->db->where("p.estado","1");
    $this->db->order_by('id',"desc");
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Comment: Si explicas por qué, mucho mejor ;)